# Stack overflow in nested loop in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, stack-overflow

I made a constructor in my program but it kept giving me the stack overflow exception. I tried changing parameters but it did not help...

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    For i As Integer = 0 To i = 12
        For j As Integer = 0 To i = 9
            atomcode(i, j) = (i * 10000 + j * 1000 + 99)
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read this on how to ask a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask  Show the call stack and the exception stack, how is atomcode() defined?  We are not mind readers.

Comment: If I ask why the last parameter in the second "for" statement is an "i", am I just revealing that I don't understand the problem?

Comment: @OldProgrammer atomcode(i,j) is *probably* a two-dimensional array. VB uses parentheses instead of square brackets for array access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you tried typing your code in, or pasted your code. The format of your [`For` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5z06z1kb.aspx) is wrong and in the second statement you are using `j` and `i` both which if it worked would be incrementing j until `i` is = 9 which would cause your stackoverflow. something like this simple console program example should work.  Also the only way your above code will compile is if you have `Option Strict Off`, do yourself a favor and place [`Option Strict On`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) at the top of your Class, it will prevent implicit narrowing conversions and save you a lot of grief.

```
Option Strict On
Module Module1
    Dim atomcode(,) As Integer

    Sub Main()
        ReDim atomcode(12, 9)
        For i As Integer = 0 To 12
            For j As Integer = 0 To 9
                atomcode(i, j) = (i * 10000 + j * 1000 + 99)
            Next j
        Next i

    End Sub 

End Module
```

Comment: tht din help it still keeps me giving the overflow error I have initialized atomcode as a two dimensional array. is there an issue about it being a constructor?

Comment: This code works in a Form constructor also., without any errors. You need to show more code, especially where you are creating your array. Usually StackOverflow errors are called by recursively calling a function. Nothing in the code you have shown is doing that.

Comment: these are all my declarations code Public Class Constructor

    Dim atomcode(12, 9) As Integer
    Dim obj As Integer
    Dim active As Boolean = False
    Dim obg As New Constructor
    Dim i, j, k As Integer

Comment: using option strict anywhere gives me a load of errors which I have never heard about..

Comment: That is because you are letting VB do a lot of implicit narrowing conversions. Read the link on Option Strict that I put in the answer

Comment: Can you put a link to your code on [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/) and paste the link in the comments, because what I am seeing here in your declarations is not making any sense without seeing the entire code.

Comment: Hey Mark! I solved my error...nothing was funny with the code...I unnecessarily initialized an object of the constructor to call it like we do in C++...deleting that declaration solved ma prob!

Comment: I am glad you figured it out. The constructor is what prompted me to ask for more code. Your For statements were wrong.  And I would still suggest that you turn Option Strict On it will prevent you from making hard to find mistakes.

Comment: well Mark thanks for the advice but I'm just a novice and I'm not going to use the strict option till i'm completely aware of everything about it.